# Java application in Microsoft PowePoint 2010

Tags: java, powerpoint

I needed to make the presentation of a business project in powerpoint, but needed to hold the demonstration of a live application in JAVA. Well wonder whether there is any way to embed a simple Java (*.jar) application running on a slide in Microsoft PowerPoint 2010 and can then carry the presentation to be shown on another computer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The only way you can really do this is to use [Liveweb](http://skp.mvps.org/liveweb.htm). A long time ago Open Office supported embedded java applets, but this was discontinued. You would need to host the applet somewhere (even locally would work), and then using Liveweb embed the page into your presentation.

Details on install can be found on the liveweb website and [here](http://www.ehow.com/how_4967102_put-applet-powerpoint.html).

Hope this helps!

-Mike